# Rotate through messages on click with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a div that rotates through messages as they are clicked with jquery. I'm not sure why the following doesnt work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#box").html("message1");
$("#box").click(function() {
    if ($("#box").html("message1"))
      {
      $("#box").html("message2");
      }
    else if ($("#box").html("message2"))
      {
      $("#box").html("message3");
      }
    else if ($("#box").html("message3"))
      {
      $("#box").html("message1");
      }
});
});
```

When you click the div, it will switch from message 1 to message 2. But when you click it again, it wont change again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
if ($("#box").html("message1"))
```

doen't check if the `html` is `message1` instead it sets the `html` to `message1` and returns a jQuery object corresponding to `#box` so the above code will always be true. That's why you always get the content changed to `message2` .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#box").html("message1");
$("#box").click(function() {
    var box = $(this);//Cache the object
    if (box .html() == "message1")
      {
      box.html("message2");
      }
    else if (box.html() == "message2")
      {
      box.html("message3");
      }
    else if (box.html() == "message3")
      {
      box.html("message1");
      }
});
});
```

---

You might want to look at the [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method which might be suitable in your case instead of `.html()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still new a noob at javascript :P

Answer (score 0):

You are using setters. .html("value") will set the value of the referenced element. So the first $("#box").html("message1") is always setting the message. I'd recommend you using an array for the messages - or if you still want to use the current approach, check for the message value with

```
if($("#box").html() == "message1") //and then continue from here
    ...
```

instead of using .html with a value in it. .html() is the getter whilst .html(value) is the setter.

**EDIT:** I could not resist. Of course you can setup your code everytime to check whether the message is a certain message - but you can imagine the amount of work for 10 pages with 10 messages each. This smallish plugin will handle an array with all the messages you want to iterate through with very little effort:

```
//plugin definition
(function($) {
    $.fn.messageListRotate = function(messageList) {
        var messages = messageList; //pass an array here
        var max = messages.length - 1;
        var pos = 1;

        //initializing the element with the first message           
        $(this).html(messages[0]);

        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).html(messages[pos]);
            pos = pos == max ? 0 : pos + 1;
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

You then use it:

```
//in your <head></head> area, after having it defined:
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //assuming you element's id is 'messages'
        $("#messages").messageListRotate(["first", "second", "third"]);
    });
</script>
```

And of course your element in your <body>:

```
<div id="messages"></div>
```

And *voilà*. Rotating on click. See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/myriad/CqcYk/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery html() method doesn't test true or false. Grab the value with html() and then test it against your values.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#box").html("message1");
$("#box").click(function() {
if ($("#box").html() == "message1")
  {
  $("#box").html("message2");
  }
else if ($("#box").html() == "message2")
  {
  $("#box").html("message3");
  }
else if ($("#box").html() == "message3")
  {
  $("#box").html("message1");
  }
});
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/GC9B4/

Answer (score 0):

Solution

http://jsfiddle.net/vM8kY/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#box").html("message1");
    $("#box").click(function() {

        if ($("#box").html() == ("message3")) {
            console.log('a');
            $("#box").html("message1");
            return false;
        }

        if ($("#box").html() == ("message2")) {
            console.log('b');
            $("#box").html("message3");
            return false;
        }

        if ($("#box").html() == ("message1")) {
            console.log('c');
            $("#box").html("message2");
            return false;
        }




    });
});
```